# SSRS: Deploy a report to my reporting server

Tags: deployment, reporting-services

I have a report project that has a bunch of reports in it.. 
all those reports were deployed to my staging server.
now I have created a new report and I want that also to be deployed to the server.
Can anyone help me with the steps to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have created a new report solution then:

Step 1: Right click on solution you will find report server URL and target folder path both this attribute you need to set and just click deploy by right cllcking on the report in solution explorer.

Step 2: If you have added in the existing solution then just deploy it in simple way.

Both this steps please ensure the datasource connection is same if they are not then just deploy the connection also not a big deal.

Refer the images for better clarity.

[image: Deploy Whole Solution]

[image: Set Properties for report deployement of new reports]